# Implementing alternative Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, fibonacci

[image]

So I'm struggling with Question 3. I think the representation of L would be a function that goes something like this:

```
import numpy as np
def L(a,  b):
    #L is 2x2 Matrix, that is 
    return(np.dot([[0,1],[1,1]],[a,b]))


def fibPow(n):
    if(n==1):
        return(L(0,1))
    if(n%2==0):
        return np.dot(fibPow(n/2), fibPow(n/2))
    else:
        return np.dot(L(0,1),np.dot(fibPow(n//2), fibPow(n//2)))
```

Given b I'm pretty sure I'm wrong. What should I be doing? Any help would be appreciated. I don't think I'm supposed to use the golden ratio property of the Fibonacci series. What should my a and b be?

EDIT: I've updated my code. For some reason it doesn't work. L will give me the right answer, but my exponentiation seems to be wrong. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The question isn't clear enough, can you attach an image of the full question?

Comment: That is the full question. Is the quality not good

Comment: Although in this case it's clear enough, `f` is nowhere defined in that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an edited code, you are almost there. Just don't cram everything into one function. That leads to subtle mistakes, which I think you may enjoy to find.

Now, `L` is not  function. As I said before, it is a matrix. And the core of the problem is to compute its `n`th power. Consider

```
L = [[0,1], [1,1]]

def nth_power(matrix, n):
    if n == 1:
        return matrix
    if (n % 2) == 0:
        temp = nth_power(matrix, n/2)
        return np.dot(temp, temp)
    else:
        temp = nth_power(matrix, n // 2)
        return np.dot(matrix, np.dot(temp, temp))

def fibPow(n):
    Ln = nth_power(L, n)
    return np.dot(L, [0,1])[1]
```

The `nth_power` is almost identical to your approach, with some trivial optimization. You may optimize it further by eliminating recursion.

Comment: @pasha Think about the dimensionality. In your implementation the base case of `fibPow` returns a vector (1x2). The `np.dot` of two such vectors returns a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, there is no `L(n, a, b)`. There is just `L(a, b)`, a well defined linear operator which transforms a vector `a, b` into a vector `b, a+b`.

Now a huge hint: a linear operator is a matrix (in this case, 2x2, and very simple). Can you spell it out?

Now, applying this matrix `n` times in a row to an initial vector (in this case, `0, 1`), by matrix magic is equivalent to applying `n`th power of L *once* to the initial vector. This is what Question 2 is about.

Once you determine how this matrix looks like, `fibPow` reduces to computing its `n`th power, and multiplying the result by `0, 1`. To get `O(log n)` complexity, check out exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: That matrix thing was what I missed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey I updated the question. Do you think you could tell me what I'm doing wrong